# Flask-SocketIo | After logging in Chrome dosen't return session['name'] value but Firefox does

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

When I log in using User-id Chrome doesn't return the Users name using session['name'], which I provided using the flasks session. But firefox does.

[**Chrome Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQWAJ.png)

[**Firefox Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmWzT.png)

**Python**

```
 @app.route('/')
 @app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def login():       
    if request.method == 'POST':
    if Users.is_user(request.form['username'],request.form['password']):
        name = Users.get_name(request.form['username'])
        session['name'] = name
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))   
return render_template("login.html",**{'session':session})

 @app.route('/get_name',methods=['GET'])
def get_name():
    data = {'name' : ''}
    if NAME_KEY in session:
        data = {'name':session['name']}
    return jsonify(data)
```

**JS**

```
const socket = io("https://"+document.domain+":"+location.port); 
async function get_Name(){
    return fetch("/get_name")
    .then(function (response) {
        return  response.json();   
       })
       .then(function (text) {  
         return text["name"];
       });
}
socket.on('connect', async function() {
var usr_name =  await get_Name();
console.log(usr_name);
if(usr_name != ''){
    var data = {
        'name': usr_name,
        'msg': 'User has connected!'
    };
    socket.emit('message',data);    
}
```

Chrome returns an empty username, whereas Firefox returns logged username

Comment: I don't see that is browser compatibility issue if the session is implement on flask server. can you add some more context to your code

Comment: I have hosted the web app on Heroku,

Comment: can you check in chrome inspect  if you're getting any cors error

Comment: I have used CORS(app) from flask_cors to prevent any cors errors, and there aren't any cors errors.